# How to calculate Credit VaR?

Tags: value-at-risk, credit-risk

(source John Hull, Options Futures and Other Derivatives 8th edition)

I can't follow why Hull calculates Credit VaR in the following manner. I thought CVaR was Unexpected Loss$_{confidence}$ - Expected Loss.

Hull calculates the 1 year 99.9% worst case default rate as:

$V(confidence,T) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(PD)+(\sqrt{p}) N^{-1}(confidence)}{\sqrt{p}})$

CVaR = portfolio value * $V(confidence, T)$ * Loss Given Default

(in the given example, he get correlation (P) via a Guassian copula)

Comment: Why do you think it should be calculated differently from Hull's formula?

Comment: I thought credit var is unexpected loss = 99.9% quantile - Expected Loss where expected loss = pd*ead*lgd

Comment: What is the reference for your statement?

Comment: Malz cites this approach. I think one of the BIS papers does too.  I dont have the source handy.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing C-VaR and capital requirements for the credit risk of a counterparty. C-VaR is given by the Hull's formula you wrote, whereas what you call "Malz approach" is the calculation of the capital requirements. Check Hull - Risk Management and Financial Institutions p. 341.

Comment: Thanks. After more digging, I've come across both the method Hull uses and the one Malz describes .."The *standard* definition of credit Value-at-Risk is cast in terms of UL (Unexpected Loss) : It is the worst case loss on a portfolio with some specific confidence level over a specific holding period, minus the expected loss".

Comment: Further found this definition from the BIS paper An Explanitory Note on the Basel II Risk Weight functions .. *"The likelihood that losses will exceed the sum of Expected Loss (EL) and Unexpected Loss (UL) - i.e. the likelihood that a bank will not be able to meet its own credit obligations by its profits and capital - equals the hatched area under the right hand side of the curve. 100% minus this likelihood is called the 
confidence level and the corresponding threshold is called Value-at-Risk (VaR) at this confidence level"*

Not questioning Hull, just trying to understand it.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness don't hesitate to accept/vote up answers if you're satisfied.

Comment: Hi Srkx,  i will when i get a chance to review it in a day or so.